# What is the difference between these two equations and when do I apply each one of them?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

So I was looking through my notes and found these two equations:
$$t' = t\gamma + \frac{\gamma\beta x}{c}$$
and
$$t' = t\gamma$$
The first equation is just deduced by applying an x axis boost, and the second is (from what I noticed) for an object moving in general (maybe radially?), but why are the two of them different let's say in the case of a body moving along the x direction with an observer centered at $(0,0)$? In other words, when should I apply each of those formulae?

Comment: I am not sure about the reference where you saw both equations, but anyway I guess the second equation is for time interval and the first one is for time coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is a special case of the first.

The first calculates the time measurement from a relatively moving frame (at x-velocity $\beta$) of an event which has (ct,x) coordinates in another frame, with a synchonization of the ($t=0,x=0$) and ($t'=0,x'=0$) coordinates.

The second would be true for an event which occurs at $x=0$. That's probably not how you are going to use it. The difference in time between two events is usually how the second happens:$$\Delta t'=\gamma\Delta t.\tag{A}$$

Let's see how this happens:
If we look at both the position and time boosts $S\to S'$ for a pair of events, we have
\begin{align}
c\Delta t' &= \gamma c\Delta t -\gamma\beta\Delta x\\
\Delta x' &= \gamma \Delta x -\gamma\beta c\Delta t\\
\end{align}

If both events in $S$ happen at the same $x$ position, then we have Equation $(A)$.

#### An Aside for length contraction

If you are concerned about a length measurement in each frame, you must remember that the events would be two position measurement of each observer, and must be made with a $\Delta t=0 $ in $S$, versus a $\Delta t'=0$ in $S'$. That means that in $S'$ we get
$$0= \gamma c\Delta t -\gamma\beta\Delta x$$
or $$ \gamma c\Delta t =\gamma\beta\Delta x$$

With that we get the length in $S'$ to be
$$\Delta x' = \gamma \left(1 -\beta^2\right) \Delta x = \frac{\Delta x}{\gamma}$$

#### Admonition

Whenever you are considering any equation, you need to consider what the assumptions or special conditions are. Your question is good in that it shows you want to understand those conditions.  Shortcut equations are good *only* if you know the conditions that made them a shortcut.